# Steinway Piano Fuzziness/Distortion and "Click sound"

Tags: piano, logic

So I am a beginner when it comes to sound producing and mixing in DAW's and that inexperience is hindering my compositions.

I've created a piano song, using only the Steinway piano with 2 layers. When playing certain parts, the sound seems to distort with a fuzzy static emanating afterwards. I can even narrow down which note causes it (c#, as well as a few others). Not only that, but whenever a note is played, a noticeable "thud" precedes it. It is especially noticeable on soft, low velocity notes. (listen to the ending, which is where I have the most discontent regarding that)

Now, on to the details. Nothing is peaking/clipping at all, it stays within green and doesn't even enter yellow at all. I've turned off "tape delay" and compression which managed to lighten the issue but the fuzzy problem still persists. I've tried multiple speakers and headphones. All velocities are under 45.

**Overall the sound is tinny, cold and empty. Does anyone know of any setting manipulation that can help produce a warm, full piano sound? Mimicking a real grand piano recording would be ideal.**

Here, I've linked a video containing the sound piece on YouTube, as this is where I intend to have the final product.

Please help if you can! Thanks!
-Steven

Comment: I actually loved the piece along with the sound. I'd change nothing. Also trying to get advice without providing a reference track is a bit hard. But still , i don't know if you're after that fake reverby compressed piano sound,your track sounds truthful and the sound has adequate body. A way you could capture that better is with an MS recording technique or other stereo techniques , but hey ... i'd *really* change nothing. Good job.

Comment: It doesn't sound bad to me, but it definitely has a lot of hammer-thump. I don't know that particular sampled piano, but if it doesn't have separate 'noises' control, then perhaps have a look at the [ToonTrack EZ-Keys](http://www.toontrack.com/product/ezkeys-grand-piano/) piano, which has adjustable 'thumps & squeaks' separate from the piano sound itself. [In defence of the sample you're using... tbh, pianos are noisy beasts anyway when close-miked]

Comment: to: frcake Thanks for the kind words! In hindsight, you're right, I should've linked another piece for reference...noted for next time! And if it sounds fine to you I'm probably being a little too analytical. Eh, either way, it's not too concerning since this will simply be an ambient score for a short film I'm making. Thanks again for the input!

Comment: to: Tetsujin Good to hear some reassurance that it's not happening to others. I'll take a look into a possible hammer adjustment in the settings too, thanks for the suggestion!